# Using \ifthenelse for setting color of Tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I would like to make use of some shorthand for drawing boxes in Tikz.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring} 

\newcommand\makeButton[3]{
    \node (rect) at #1 [fill=magenta] {#3};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\makeButton{(1,1)}{1}{Click here.}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like the second argument of `\makeButton` to set the color of the button. (The button should be magenta if #2==1, and cyan otherwise.) So I replaced the `\newcommand` in the example above by

```
\newcommand\makeButton[3]{
    \node (rect) at #1 [fill=\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{1}}{magenta}{cyan}] {#3};
}
```

This return the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {1}{1}
l.15 \makeButton{(1,1)}{1}{Click here.}
```

If I replace `\equal{#2}{1}` with some dummy condition for now,

```
\newcommand\makeButton[3]{
    \node (rect) at #1 [fill=\ifthenelse{15>10}{magenta}{cyan}] {#3};
}
```

... I still get an error:

```
! Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 \makeButton{(1,1)}{1}{Click here.}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ifnum` of Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418182/16967) is expandable and can be used in the value part for key `fill`. This is shown in the definition of `\makeButtonA`.

`\ifcase` is also expandable and expects an integer. It is useful for consecutive numbers as shown in `\makeButtonB`. Although `\ifcase` can be used inside the value for `fill`, the color is defined outside as macro to get a clearer source code.

Also `\ifthenelse` can be used (for the fans of `ifthen`). But then the color 
must be defined outside in a non-expandable context. This is shown in the definition of `\makeButtonC`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}% also loads xcolor
\usepackage{ifthen}

% Expandable \ifnum
\newcommand{\makeButtonA}[3]{%
  \node at #1 [fill={\ifnum#2=1 magenta\else cyan\fi}] {#3};
}

% Present \ifcase
\newcommand*{\makeButtonB}[3]{%
  \edef\ButtonFillColor{%
    \ifcase\numexpr(#2)\relax
      black% 0
    \or magenta% 1
    \or cyan% 2
    \or red% 3
    \or green% 4
    \or blue% 5
    \else black%
    \fi
  }
  \node at #1 [fill=\ButtonFillColor] {#3};
}

% A variant with \ifthenelse
\newcommand*{\makeButtonC}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{1}}{%
    \colorlet{ButtonFillColor}{magenta}%
  }{%
    \colorlet{ButtonFillColor}{cyan}%
  }%
  \node at #1 [fill=ButtonFillColor] {#3};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-8mm]
  \makeButtonA{(1,1)}{1}{Click here A1.}
  \makeButtonA{(1,2)}{15}{Click here A2.}
  \makeButtonB{(1,3)}{1}{Click here B1.}
  \makeButtonB{(1,4)}{2}{Click here B2.}
  \makeButtonB{(1,5)}{3}{Click here B3.}
  \makeButtonC{(1,6)}{1}{Click here C1.}
  \makeButtonC{(1,7)}{15}{Click here C2.}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, Heiko! I ended up using your solution for my work. I am using `\makeButton` to place a lot of buttons using a for loop. For that application, a command that accepts numbers as colour specifiers is easier to work with than a command that requires string inputs. For ''manual use'', I think Werner's `\NewDocumentCommand`is the most intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Your setting of the colour should be expandable. Here's a way to do it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\newcommand{\makeButtonA}[3]{%
  \ifnum#2=1
    \node at #1 [fill=magenta] {#3};
  \else % #2 != 1
    \node at #1 [fill = cyan] {#3};
  \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeButtonB}{m O{magenta} m}{%
  \node at #1 [fill = #2] {#3};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \makeButtonA{(1,1)}{1}{Click here A1.}
  \makeButtonA{(1,2)}{15}{Click here A2.}
  \makeButtonB{(1,3)}{Click here B1.}
  \makeButtonB{(1,4)}[cyan]{Click here B2.}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've also included an [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) option that provides an optional second argument `\makeButtonB{<coord>}[<colour>]{<text>}`, where the default is `magenta`, unless specified otherwise. It might be a more intuitive interface rather than specifying a "colour" using a "number".